# Divio App trouble to create project directory and clone repository

Tags: django, docker, divio

Please help I have trouble with Divio App trying to making it work.
When I press "set up project"
it gives me this

*

```
Creating workspace
cloning project repository
Cloning into '/c/Users/Ubisoft/Documents/iloveit'...
Bad owner or permissions on /home/divio/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
There was an error trying to run a command. This is most likely
not an issue with divio-cli, but the called program itself.
Try checking the output of the command above.
The command was:
  git clone git@git.divio.com:iloveit.git /c/Users/Ubisoft/Documents/iloveit
```

*

and in windows power shell it gives me this

```
Creating workspace

cloning project repository
Cloning into '/c/Users/Ubisoft/Documents/iloveit'...
Bad owner or permissions on /home/divio/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
There was an error trying to run a command. This is most likely
not an issue with divio-cli, but the called program itself.
Try checking the output of the command above.
The command was:
  git clone git@git.divio.com:iloveit.git /c/Users/Ubisoft/Documents/iloveit

divio@app-1.0.0 /c/Users/Ubisoft/Documents
$
```

I also tried this from virtual MacOS and getting this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QccvY.png

I also tried to mess arouond with creating SSH keys but didn't work out.

Can someone provide me step by step explanation how to make this wonderful app work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may face this issue. On my MacOS virtual machine I managed to find solution. Looks like it is Internet Service Provider blocking port 22 something like that. Okay looks like problem resolved. I used VPN and without any hastle with SSH I got different result. Looks like it is working now not finished creating project yet but promising:

```
Creating workspace

cloning project repository
Cloning into '/Users/johnwick/Documents/best-project'...
Locking the website...
remote: Counting objects: 785, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (739/739), done.
Unlocking the website...(385/785), 1.05 MiB | 524.00 KiB/s
remote: Total 785 (delta 112), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (785/785), 1.77 MiB | 448.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (112/112), done.
Checking out files: 100% (615/615), done.
downloading remote docker images
Pulling db  ... done
Pulling web ... done
building local docker images
db uses an image, skipping
Building web
Step 1/7 : FROM divio/base:4.15-py3.6-slim-stretch
4.15-py3.6-slim-stretch: Pulling from divio/base
```

Comment: It is not clear how using a VPN would make a difference to the `Bad owner or permissions on /home/divio/.ssh/config` error.

Comment: Yes I did not try VPN with windows computer yet. Just it worked on MacOS.

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that on windows 10 pro the divio app did not run nicely. So I had to use Docker Tools manual installation and running with Hyper V turned off and VT-x turned on. And it made me able to install Divio app until that error point. But later I will try it with VPN and see if that helps.

Comment: couldnt make it on windows

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows examples you show, I see:

```
Bad owner or permissions on /home/divio/.ssh/config
```

I am not sure how that has happened, but that is what is preventing your local environment from providing the expected key to the Divio Control Panel.

In the Macintosh example, the environment doesn't have a key that the Control Panel knows about.

You will need to add the key (probably from `~/.ssh/rsa_id.pub`) to https://control.divio.com/account/ssh-keys/. If you don't already have a key in the Macintosh environment, you will need to set one up.

Comment: i thought maybe u can help me if i made something wrong in my steps on installing. but maybe it is something wrong with my internet service provider like if they not allow port 22 or something... i must try from other ways i guess from other countries or using VPN and see what happens

Comment: Okay looks like problem resolved. I used VPN and without any hastle with SSH I got different result. Looks like it is working now not finished creating project yet but promising: